# SQL Query: Get All <ParentTableRecord>s not matched to a <Child> with attribute value = <value>

Tags: sql

Suppose I have a table, [Owner], with only a "Name". Then I have a table [Dog], with a "Name", a "LeashColor", and an "OwnerName".

Sample data:

```
Owner: <Name: Joe>, <Name: Sue>
Dog: <Name: Rover, LeashColor: Red, OwnerName: Joe>,
     <Name: Pup, LeashColor: Green, OwnerName: Joe>,
     <Name: Spot, LeashColor: Purple, OwnerName: Sue>,
     <Name: Lassie, LeashColor: Yellow, OwnerName: Sue>
```

I would like a SQL query that gets all owners without a dog named .  For example, the query, when the input  = "Rover", would return Sue because she does not have a dog named Rover, but Joe does.

If possible, it would be even better to have a query that gets all owners without a dog named , but if they do have a dog named , get them if the dogs leash color is

So, with input,  = "Rover" and  = "Red", both Joe and Sue would be returned (Sue not having a Rover, Joe having a Rover with a red leash).  But, if the input is "Rover", "Green", only Sue would be returned (Sue not having a rover, Joe having a Rover and color not being green).

I've been puzzling over this one for a while.  I would be very grateful for any tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NOT IN` to find records that are not in a given subquery:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Owner
WHERE Name NOT IN
(SELECT Name from Dog 
 WHERE Name = @dogName)
```

You can use a LEFT JOIN for the second results:

```
SELECT o.* 
FROM Owner o
LEFT JOIN Dog d
    ON o.Name = d.OwnerName
    AND d.Name = @dogName
WHERE d.Name IS NULL  // no dog by that name
     OR d.LeashColor = @leashColor  // dog by than name with the right color leash
```